# Detect intersection in constant time?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, integers

I'm working in an algorithm and one of the steps requires me to check whether or not 2 sequences of integers are what I call 'compatible' this is, their intersection is empty. I managed to make this intersection procedure O(n) but I was wondering if there was a way to make it even faster.

The sequences I have look like this:

<0 1 2 3 4 8>, <2 3 4 5 9> so these two sequences wouldn't be compatible because their intersection <2 3 4> is not empty.

I do not REQUIRE to perform the intersection procedure, this is just the way I came up with to know whether or not they share an integer.

I tried assigning each sequence a number such as the sum of the squares of all integers in the sequence:

For sequence $<x_1,x_2,x_3>$ this approach would assign $x_1^2+x_2^2+x^3_3$, then I'd say that if the assigned integer of sequence $s_1$ is equal to the assigned integer of sequence $s_2$ then $s_1$ and $s_2$ have an integer in common, but this is not the case in general.

I do not need to know which integer they share in common, I just need to know whether they share one(or more) or not. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This should generally not be possible as the intersecting number can be the last one of each sequence, thus requiring you to scan each sequence entirely. Even if you could assign a number to a given sequence, computing that number would still take linear time. I'm not even sure you can intersect them in linear time without assuming them to be sorted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say they're indeed sorted.